# Are there any words that perfectly rhyme with the past tense of -ɪdəl words, that aren't conjugations of other words?

Tags: rhymes

[-ɪdəl](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rhymes:English/%C9%AAd%C9%99l) words.

I'm looking for perfect rhymes with "riddled" that aren't just other forms of other words. Do any exist?

Comment: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-that-end-in-led

Comment: Many pronounce _ribald_ as an oblique rhyme of 'riddled'.

Comment: Riddled is also an adjective according to [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/riddled),

Comment: @Gio - And all of those seem to be past-tense, which isn't what I want?

Comment: @Malady - well, you can draw your conclusion from that list

Comment: Like others have said, past-tense words are also participles and so can be used as adjectives too without any past-tense implication. But the reason for my comment is, if you don't like any of the "-ddled" words on offer in rhyming lists because they don't fit the situation, remember that you're American and generally pronounce a "t" in middle of a word like a "d," so you can also use "-ttled" words too, like "belittled," "whittled," etc. (e.g., The man felt angry and belittled.). There's also combining words, like stressing "fit" in "fit old" would rhyme with "riddled" (e.g., a fit old man).

Comment: @BenjaminHarman - Thanks for inspiring me to specify that I'm looking for perfect rhymes!

Comment: _Piddled_ and _diddled_ are both regular verb forms. Though using them together in rhymes does color the poem a bit.